# Output a tuple of one record and all other records Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I need to emit a tuple from Reducer that contains one of the records with each of other records. For example, if Reducer gets:

```
key1, value1
key1, value2
key1, value3
key1, value4
key2, value5
key2, value6
key2, value7
```

I need to select one of the values for each of the keys somehow and emit it with all the other values, concretely, let's say that value2 is selected for key1 and value6 is selected form key2. I need to emit from the reducer the following:

```
key1, value1, value2
key1, value2, value2
key1, value3, value2
key1, value4, value2
key2, value5, value6
key2, value6, value6
key2, value7, value6
```

As you can see I need to go through the values twice, once to get the value2 (for example) and once to emit it with all the other records.

As I am aware of, you cannot iterate through values twice, and my assumption that the dataset is too large to fit the memory, so I cannot buffer the values.

My other idea is to emit each record twice, and have two different keys, for example key1a and key1b, so I could iterate once through values to select, and iterate second time to emit records. Is there any other way to do it?

I don't want to split this into multiple jobs, since this is only one part of a much larger process.

Comment: you cannot even buffer the values of each key (and reset the buffer each time you meet a new key)?

Comment: @vefthym No, the number of keys is small and the dataset is expected to be large. Also, values are not that small (at least I think that they could be considered like that, values are double vectors that can have length of minimum 500 elements, up to couple of thousands, so it's not just a single value). Thanks for your interest.